# How to get Top N most similar items based on cosine similarity results in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions, cosine-similarity

I have a dataset of images ( id, url, features ) on which I performed a Cosine Similarity between all images. The result is a pyspark dataframe with the following structure :

```
>>> cos_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vec: vector (nullable = true)
```

vec is a column that contains the results of the cosine similarity ( DenseVector ).
What I'm trying to do is to create a column "similar_urls" OR update "vec" and input, for each row, the top N most similar items based on the vec column values.

For example, if I take id = 26, I want to look in "vec" and find the indexes of the top N items ( id and indexes are the same ) and replace the values of vec with a list of the url of the top N items.

What I tried to do is to :

1. replace "vec" with a list/array of top N most similar items' indexes (udf)
2. replace that list/array with a list/array of urls (udf)

I'm stuck at the first step because I can't seem to transform my "vec" values into an array/list to find the top 10 values.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def convert_to_array(vec):
    return type(vec)

test_udf = udf(convert_to_array, StringType())

cos_df = cos_df.withColumn("vec", test_udf("vec"))
```

When I try to look at the type of vec values, it returns

```
net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor@2db673eb
```

Do you have any idea of what type is that and how can I manipulate it so that I can transform vec ?

P.S : I am also open to any other solution that would be better for the given problem!

Comment: What would be the ideal output for you ? An array of float ?

Comment: I found a solution for 1. But i'm still trying to figure out how to match my list of indexes with my ids in order to retrieve the urls of the top N items for the step 2.

Comment: you need first to create a python function that retrieve the URLs you need. Your problem is independent from spark. Once you have this function, just transform it in UDF with type `ArrayType(StringType())`. But without knowing what kind of object your vector is, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with that solution for 1., it seems to work.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def convert_to_array(vec):
    vec_list = vec.tolist()
    sorted_top = sorted(range(len(vec_list)), key=lambda i: vec_list[i], reverse=True)[1:16]
    return sorted_top

test_udf = udf(convert_to_array, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

cos_df = cos_df.withColumn("similar_url", test_udf("vec"))
```